# All tracks by Henrik Zeabird?

Tags: henrik-zeabird, discography

Has Henrik Zeabird ever performed or even released other works than the three songs published on [their Myspace page](https://myspace.com/henrikzeabird)?

- [*Rain*](https://myspace.com/henrikzeabird/music/song/rain-77612628-85521042)
- [*Up and Down*](https://myspace.com/henrikzeabird/music/song/up-and-down-77612506-85520955)
- [*jahreszeiten*](https://myspace.com/henrikzeabird/music/song/jahreszeiten-78414200-86369725)

[Their Bandcamp page](http://henrikzeabird.bandcamp.com/releases) only lists *Rain*, YouTube only contains one [video where they perform *Rain*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUC07ne_bXE), Vimeo also contains only a [(different) video where they perform *Rain*](https://vimeo.com/18969603).

It seems they performed on some events/festivals … maybe with some other songs?

Answer (score 2):

[Their BandPage page](http://www.bandpage.com/s/HenrikZeabird) (which is [included](https://www.facebook.com/henrik.zeabird/app_178091127385) in their Facebook page) lists (and allows to stream/download) 8 songs.
But according to the file’s numbering, there should be a ninth track. When sharing one of the tracks, it is revealed that they come from a [SoundCloud set from andimu](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/sets/henrik-zeabird), which contains 9 songs (BandPage misses the bonus track *Pirate*):

1. [*How the Hail Works*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/1-how-the-hail-works)
2. [*Drink myself to Sleep*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/2-drink-myself-to-sleep)
3. [*Dwelling*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/3-dwelling)
4. [*Mountain*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/4-mountain)
5. [*After Years of Sleep*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/5-tired-after-years-of-sleep)
   (according to file name: *Tired After Years of Sleep*)
6. [*Gone*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/6-my-tape)
   (according to the file name: *My Tape*)
7. [*Savour the Flavour*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/7-sleep-walking)
   (according to the file name: *Sleep Walking*)
8. [*Outro*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/8-outro)
9. [*Pirate (Bonus)*](https://soundcloud.com/andimu/9-pirate-bonus)

That makes **12 tracks** in total (of which 2, *Up and Down* and *jahreszeiten*, can’t be downloaded).

I couldn’t find out if they ever performed other songs at an event.